# Push sensor data from arduino to apache kafka server directly.

Tags: arduino, apache-kafka, iot

I am new to Internet Of things. I have pushed temperature data to mosquito server and successfully consumed all data. Now I want to push data from arduino to kafka server and consume from kafka. Is there any kafka library for arduino?
What architecture will be suitable for scaling mqqt using apache kafka?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna take a look at the below article for the architecture and scalability part of your design:

http://www.confluent.io/blog/stream-data-platform-1/

Not tying the answer to a particular language- but personally I find Kafka Library for Java is much more mature than the counterparts.

You could easily write a wrapper around the arduino library (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/li.rudin.arduino/arduino-api), that collects the data as input and streams it real-time to Kafka as kafka-producer using the library (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.10).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Arduino Yun` to build your `IoT` application(s), yes!

Arduino Yun contains two processors, one of these processors runs `OpenWRT` linux distribution. You can simply port `kafka` to this OS and run `kafka` client to push data to `apache kafka` server.

I've done it myself. To do this, you simply have to access the `Yun`'s root by doing `ssh` from the terminal.

Run

```
$ opkg install update
```

Download the `kafka` library written in `Python` (`OpenWRT` has `Python` already installed).

Run `Python` `kafka` script inside your OS as client. Make sure you have your `Yun` connected to the network. Poof! It is working now.